# Box each element of a matrix

Tags: tikz-matrix

I want elements $A_0,A_1 \cdots A_l,Z_1,Z_2, \cdots Z_d$ to be put inside a box. I have written the following code.

```
\documentclass[13pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amssymb,mathtools,nccmath}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%
\newcommand\cbox[1]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture,baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax]\node[rectangle,fill=blue!50,fill opacity = 0.2,draw,thick,text opacity =1] {$#1$};}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\textbf{F}~~ = ~~ 
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{matrix}
a_{10}~~~\cbox{A_0}\\[0.22cm]
a_{20}~~~\cbox{A_0}\\[0.22cm]
\vdots\\
a_{l0}~~~\cbox{A_0}\\
\end{matrix} & ~~\vline~~ &
\begin{matrix}
\cbox{A_1}\\[0.22cm]
\cbox{A_2}\\[0.22cm]
\vdots\\
\cbox{A_l}
\end{matrix} & ~~\vline &
\begin{matrix}
a_{11}~~~\cbox{Z_1} ~~~& a_{12}~~~\cbox{Z_2} & \dots & a_{1d}~~~\cbox{Z_d}\\[0.22cm]
a_{21}~~~\cbox{Z_1} ~~~& a_{22}~~~\cbox{Z_2}& \dots & a_{2d}~~~\cbox{Z_d}\\[0.22cm]
\vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots\\
a_{l1}~~~\cbox{Z_1} ~~~& a_{l2}~~~\cbox{Z_2} & \dots & a_{ld}~~~\cbox{Z_d}\\
\end{matrix}
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

But the matrix borders overlaps with the last columns. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe you want to have a look at TikZ matrices, because they are much more flexible concerning borders…

Comment: I used tikz. Can we do this with minimal changes to this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

My personal favorite is of course the latter. Note that I also changed matrix entry `(3,5)` from `\dots` to `\ddots`.

```
\documentclass[13pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amssymb,mathtools,nccmath}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%
\newcommand\cbox[1]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture,baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax]\node[rectangle,fill=blue!50,fill opacity = 0.2,draw,thick,text opacity =1] {$#1$};}
\begin{document}
Initial:
\begin{equation*}
\textbf{F}~~ = ~~ 
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{matrix}
a_{10}~~~\cbox{A_0}\\[0.22cm]
a_{20}~~~\cbox{A_0}\\[0.22cm]
\vdots\\
a_{l0}~~~\cbox{A_0}\\
\end{matrix} & ~~\vline~~ &
\begin{matrix}
\cbox{A_1}\\[0.22cm]
\cbox{A_2}\\[0.22cm]
\vdots\\
\cbox{A_l}
\end{matrix} & ~~\vline &
\begin{matrix}
a_{11}~~~\cbox{Z_1} ~~~& a_{12}~~~\cbox{Z_2} & \dots & a_{1d}~~~\cbox{Z_d}\\[0.22cm]
a_{21}~~~\cbox{Z_1} ~~~& a_{22}~~~\cbox{Z_2}& \dots & a_{2d}~~~\cbox{Z_d}\\[0.22cm]
\vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots\\
a_{l1}~~~\cbox{Z_1} ~~~& a_{l2}~~~\cbox{Z_2} & \dots & a_{ld}~~~\cbox{Z_d}\\
\end{matrix}
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation*}

\renewcommand\cbox[1]{\tikz[baseline={(n.base)}]\node (n) [rectangle,fill=blue!10,draw,thick] {$#1$};}
Only changed \verb|\cbox| and removed \verb|~|:
\begin{equation*}
\textbf{F}\quad=\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{matrix}
        a_{10}\cbox{A_0} \\[0.22cm]
        a_{20}\cbox{A_0} \\[0.22cm]
        \vdots           \\
        a_{l0}\cbox{A_0} \\[0.22cm]
    \end{matrix}
    & \vline &
    \begin{matrix}
        \cbox{A_1} \\[0.22cm]
        \cbox{A_2} \\[0.22cm]
        \vdots     \\
        \cbox{A_l} \\[0.22cm]
    \end{matrix}
    & \vline &
    \begin{matrix}
        a_{11}\cbox{Z_1} & a_{12}\cbox{Z_2} & \dots  & a_{1d}\cbox{Z_d} \\[0.22cm]
        a_{21}\cbox{Z_1} & a_{22}\cbox{Z_2} & \dots  & a_{2d}\cbox{Z_d} \\[0.22cm]
        \vdots           & \vdots           & \ddots & \vdots           \\
        a_{l1}\cbox{Z_1} & a_{l2}\cbox{Z_2} & \dots  & a_{ld}\cbox{Z_d} \\[0.22cm]
    \end{matrix}
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation*}

Changed to single matrix, with some tweaking of \verb|\arraystretch| and extra row distance:
\begin{equation*}
\textbf{F}\quad=\quad
\left[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
\begin{array}{@{}c|c|cccc}
    a_{10}\cbox{A_0} & \cbox{A_1} & a_{11}\cbox{Z_1} & a_{12}\cbox{Z_2} & \dots  & a_{1d}\cbox{Z_d} \\
    a_{20}\cbox{A_0} & \cbox{A_2} & a_{21}\cbox{Z_1} & a_{22}\cbox{Z_2} & \dots  & a_{2d}\cbox{Z_d} \\
    \vdots           & \vdots     & \vdots           & \vdots           & \ddots & \vdots           \\[-1mm]
    a_{l0}\cbox{A_0} & \cbox{A_l} & a_{l1}\cbox{Z_1} & a_{l2}\cbox{Z_2} & \dots  & a_{ld}\cbox{Z_d} \\[1.5mm]
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice! +1. One more option: `\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand\cbox[1]{%
\tikz[overlay, remember picture,baseline=(tmp.base)]{%
\node[inner sep=0pt](tmp){$#1$};
\node[inner sep=2pt,overlay,rectangle,fill=blue!50,fill opacity = 0.2,draw,thick,
fit=(tmp)] {};}
}`. This allows you to avoid the base line computation but makes sure that the node doesn't take more space than an unboxed entry would.

Comment: @marmot Wouldn't that make the entries of `\cbox` come out as slightly bluish (because the rectangle is on top)? Also This doesn't take into account the extra horizontal width of `\cbox`, so it will be drawn over the preceding text. Maybe you can add an answer explaining what you mean (or proving me wrong :) ) ?

Comment: You're right. (You could rectify that by picking the correct blend mode but then this becomes more involved.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a hammersledge like TiKZ for this: a simple `\fcolorbox` will do.

Unrelated: there is no `13pt`  option in the standard classes (even with the `extsizes` package).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, amssymb, mathtools, nccmath}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%
\newcommand\cbox[1]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture,baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax]\node[rectangle,fill=blue!50,fill opacity = 0.2,draw,thick,text opacity =1] {$#1$};}
\colorlet{myblue}{blue!12}
\newcommand{\Cbox}[1]{\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.8pt}\fcolorbox{black}{myblue}{$ #1 $}}
\usepackage{makecell, bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}
\textbf{F}~~ = ~~
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{@{}c@{\,}c|c|*{4}{c@{\,}c}@{\,}}
a_{10} & \Cbox{A_0} & \Cbox{A_1} & a_{11} & \Cbox{Z_1} & a_{12} & \Cbox{Z_2} & \dots & \mkern-1mu\dots & a_{1d} & \Cbox{Z_d}\bigstrut[t]\\
a_{20} & \Cbox{A_0} & \Cbox{A_2} & a_{21} & \Cbox{Z_1} & a_{22} & \Cbox{Z_2}& \dots & \mkern-1mu\dots & a_{2d} & \Cbox{Z_d}\\
\vdots & & \vdots & \vdots & & & & & & & \vdots \\
a_{l0} & \Cbox{A_0} & \Cbox{A_l} & a_{l1} & \Cbox{Z_1} & a_{l2} & \Cbox{Z_2} & \dots & \mkern-1mu\dots & a_{ld} & \Cbox{Z_d}\bigstrut[b]
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]