# How to make these type of matrices?

Tags: matrices, tikz-matrix

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

How to make these type of complicated structures? I searched online but could not find any resource or examples.

Comment: Acually i have no idea how to proceed. Maybe if one helps with the first one, i can try to do the second.

Comment: You should always phrase questions like [your first one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446426/box-each-element-of-a-matrix), accompanied by a little example.  If you just post an image asking “how to do this” you are at the mercy of bored users willing to type all that up for you.  Also questions like this are not particularly interesting for most people, because they only help you and no one else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \mathsf{F} =
  \left[
    \underbrace{
      \left.
        \begin{matrix}
          \mathsf{F}_1 \doteq  \\
                               \\
          \boxed{\mathsf{A}_1} \\
          \text{or $0$}        \\
        \end{matrix}
        \middle| \quad{\cdots}\quad \middle|
        \begin{matrix}
          \mathsf{F}_\ell \doteq  \\
                                  \\
          \boxed{\mathsf{A}_\ell} \\
          \text{or $0$}           \\
        \end{matrix}
      \right.
    }_{\text{$\mathsf{A}_i$ included iff $i \in \mathsf{Attrib}$}}
  \middle|
    \begin{matrix}
      \mathsf{F}_0 \doteq  \\
                           \\
      \boxed{\mathsf{A}_0} \\
                           \\
    \end{matrix}
  \right]
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \mathsf{M} =
  \left[
    \underbrace{
      \begin{matrix}
        \boxed{\mathsf{A}_1} \\
        &\boxed{\mathsf{A}_2} \\
        &&\ddots \\
        &&&\boxed{\mathsf{A}_\ell} \\
      \end{matrix}
    }_{\text{Public, constant, from $\mathsf{Pub}$}}
  \middle|
    \underbrace{
      \begin{matrix}
        l_{1,0} \boxed{\mathsf{A}_1}                                                         \\
        l_{2,0} \boxed{\mathsf{A}_2}                                                         \\
        \vdots                                                                               \\
        l_{\ell,0} \boxed{\mathsf{A}_\ell}                                                   \\
      \end{matrix}
    }_{\text{From $\mathsf{Pub}$}}
  \middle|
    \underbrace{
      \begin{matrix}
        l_{1,1} \boxed{\mathsf{Z}_1}    & \cdots & l_{1,\theta} \boxed{\mathsf{Z}_\theta}    \\
        l_{2,1} \boxed{\mathsf{Z}_1}    & \cdots & l_{2,\theta} \boxed{\mathsf{Z}_\theta}    \\
        \vdots                          &        & \vdots                                    \\
        l_{\ell,1} \boxed{\mathsf{Z}_1} & \cdots & l_{\ell,\theta} \boxed{\mathsf{Z}_\theta} \\
      \end{matrix}
    }_{\text{Secret, random, ephermerals}}
  \right]
  \bmod q
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. For slightly more generous spacing around `\middle|`, consider inserting `\;` ("thickspace") on either side.

Comment: @Mico When using LuaTeX, you could also do `\def\middle{\Umiddle class 3}` which gives `\middle` the same spacing as `\mathrel` (which should be default in my opinion).